# iOS AVFoundation Video Capture Orientation Options

Tags: ios, avfoundation, video-capture

I have an app that I would like to have video capture for the front-facing camera only. That's no problem. But I would like the video capture to always be in landscape, even when the phone is being held in portrait.

I have a working implementation based on the AVCamDemo code that Apple published. And borrowing from the information in [this tech note](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1744/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011134), I am able to specify the orientation. There's just one trick: while the video frame is oriented correctly, the contents still appear as though shot in portrait:

[image: landscape orientation with portrait contents]

I'm wondering if I'm just getting boned by the physical constraints of the hardware: is the image sensor just oriented this way? The referenced tech note above makes this note:

> Important: Setting the orientation on a still image output and movie
>   file output doesn't physically rotate the buffers. For the movie file
>   output, it applies a track transform (matrix) to the video track so
>   that the movie is rotated on playback, and for the still image output
>   it inserts exif metadata that image viewers use to rotate the image
>   properly when viewing later.

But my playback of that video suggests otherwise. Any insight or suggestions would be appreciated!

Thanks,
Aaron.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, yes, the image sensor is just oriented that way. The video camera is an approx 1-megapixel "1080p" camera that has a fixed orientation. The 5MP (or 8MP for 4S, etc) still camera also has a fixed orientation. The lenses themselves don't rotate nor do any of the other camera bits, and hence the feed itself has a fixed orientation.

"But wait!", you say, "pictures I take with the camera app (or API) get rotated correctly. Why is that?" That's cuz iOS takes a look at the orientation of the phone when a picture is taken and stores that information with the picture (as an Exif attachment). Yet video isn't so flagged -- and each frame would have to be individually flagged, and then there's issues about what to do when the user rotates the phone *during* video....

So, no, you can't ask a video stream or a still image what orientation the phone was in when the video was captured. You can, however, directly ask the phone what orientation it is in *now*:

```
UIDeviceOrientation currentOrientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;
```

If you do that at the start of video capture (or when you grab a still image from a video feed) you can then use that information to do your own rotation of playback.