# force camera to landscape with AVFoundation

Tags: ios, camera, avfoundation, landscape, uiinterfaceorientation

I'm using the Apple's sample code for AVFoundation, here, https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVCam/AVCam.zip

I've go through the many threads and beat my mind with google too but that doesn't help.

[iPhone AVFoundation camera orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662930/iphone-avfoundation-camera-orientation)

[iOS AVFoundation Video Capture Orientation Options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6969948/ios-avfoundation-video-capture-orientation-options)

[Force camera view in landscape with orientation lock on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13833908/force-camera-view-in-landscape-with-orientation-lock-on)

[Orientation deprecated in iOS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13160407/orientation-deprecated-in-ios-6/)

[Wired behaviour of UIImagePickerController while capturing photo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24409530/wired-behaviour-of-uiimagepickercontroller-while-capturing-photo) this was my previous question for the same error but with `UIImagePickerController` then I decide to use `AVFoundation` functions.

See the (error) screenshot,

[image]

It started the camera in portrait and wrong camera preview.

Note, setting orientation in code doesn't help. That only rotated (wrongly) camera preview.

Any help/suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your project allows both Potrait and Landscape mode, You can't handle the UIImagpickerController only in landscape mode on iPhone

go through this in Developer forum:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007070-CH3-DontLinkElementID_1

Important: The UIImagePickerController class supports portrait mode only. This class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified, with one exception. You can assign a custom view to the cameraOverlayView property and use that view to present additional information or manage the interactions between the camera interface and your code.

Comment: thanks for answer, but I'm aware of this. That's why I'm switching to `AV Foundation` framework. Anyways I asked a question on that too. Just for your reference, [you can check that here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24409530/wired-behaviour-of-uiimagepickercontroller-while-capturing-photo).